# How do I get image digest when running docker buildx bake --push?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr, docker-buildkit

I'm trying to build 8 docker images at once using Docker BuildKit.
I want to avoid using the `latest` tag of the image in my Helm manifests in favor of image sha.

I've considered parsing stdout of the `docker buildx bake --push` but that doesn't have any good markers for image:hash pairs.

My simplified and trimmed bake setup:

```
target "base" {
  dockerfile = "Dockerfile.base"
  platforms = ["linux/amd64"]
}

target "app" {
  contexts = {
    baseimage = "target:base"
  }
  dockerfile = "Dockerfile.app"
  platforms = ["linux/amd64"]

  args = {
    VERSION = "${APP_VERSION}"
    TIER = "${APP_TIER}"
  }
}

target "importer" {
  inherits = ["app"]
  tags = ["${IMAGE_PREFIX}/appname:${TAG}"]

  args = {
    APP = "appname"
  }
}
```

I've considered calling AWS CLI to get the latest image hash from ECR (this is where I'm pushing to), but that is error-prone as some other job might push the image at the same time, that's why I want to get hashes of the images I just built.

Any other options I might be missing?

Also, I would like to add the blatant thing about image ID not being the same as image digest.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the digest with `docker buildx imagetools inspect`

example:

```
docker buildx imagetools inspect 0000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository:tag

Name:      0000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repository:tag
MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
Digest:    sha256:6f7671298ca9e1a6e41293d41feeeb61f173e241fc96b6f012f77537ff58a4dd
```